# Какова этимология слова "лоботряс"?

Tags: этимология, значение-слов

Есть такая версия:

> Буквально — "тот, кто трясет лбом".
>   Изначально это слово означало "дурак, остолоп, скалозуб", позднее — "бездельник". Слово "лоб" связано с понятиями "голова, ум".
>   Вероятно, тот, кто трясет лбом, считался пустоголовым, глупым.

Источник неизвестен, распространено в интернете.
У меня же есть предположение, что так пренебрежительно называли священников.

Comment: Не замечал, чтобы священники трясли головой.

Answer (score 3):

Есть пословица "Бог-то Бог, да и сам не будь плох". Лоботряс только бесконечно молится, уповает только на Бога, а сам не пытается действовать. Бездельничает и просит у Бога.

Comment: Молитва — умное делание. «Она бывает словесной, умной деятельной, умно-сердечной деятельной.., умно-сердечной самодвижной, движимой Духом Святым, и умно-сердечной чистой...» (О молитве Иисусовой и Божественной Благодати. Архиепископ Антоний). Сводить молитву к выпрашиванию чего-то неверно.

Answer (score 0):

Лоботряс
Вероятно, это перефразированное «лоботреск» от «трещать лбом», что относится к выражению «Заставь дурака молиться, он и лоб расшибёт». Однако, изрядно молиться, т.е. бить головой об пол, всё-таки работа.
Есть вариант трансформации слова «лоботряс» в «работа» с перемещением согласных Л/Р, что часто бывает.
Лоботряс > lobotrjas > rabota-risk/brezg – работа риск/брезг (слав.)(редукция r/l, пропуск k; пропуск b), т.е. рисковать чем-либо заниматься или брезговать работой - бездельничать.
Преобразования слов делается по методике поиска славянских слов в иностранных словах. http://www.tezan.ru/metod.htm

Answer (score 0):

Лоботряс и лобстер не одно и то же, но оба сойдут за глупого бездельника. Лобстер может молиться, лоботрясничать и ждать (хотя вода совсем рядом), когда же волна сама настигнет его, чтобы вытащить его из неблагоприятной ситуации. И тогда он таки начинает работать лапками.

Answer (score -1):

*Слово "лоб" связано с понятиями "голова, ум".*
Действительно, отдельно от головы лбом не потрясёшь: потрясти или сотрясти чего-либо можно как вовне, так и внутри неё (действие ведь равно противодействию), что оборачивается членовредительством и самоуничтожением.
Лоботряс — тот, кто не рассудителен и утверждается не разумом, а лишь одной мышечной силой. Что до этимологии слова, то она на поверхности, и секрета никакого в себе не содержит: строго физическое действие получило символическую окраску в одном сложном слове, которое стало прозвищем, фамилией (polkrf.ru/veterans/73861), бытовым штампом, ругательством.

Comment: При чём тут неуважение? Если это и неуважение, то не моё, а тех, кто его проявлял в такой форме. Неужели, если мы будем говорить об этимологии слова **блядь**, например, это тоже будет неуважением? Глупость с Вашей стороны, это ведь наука

Comment: Опять же, нет ни одной ссылки на какой-либо авторитетный (или, на худой конец, не авторитетный) источник. Голословное утверждение, выдаваемое за истину в первой инстанции

Answer (score -2):

Возможно лоботряс не трясёт головой, это с ним произошло  единожды. Головой ударился. Сотрясение мозга, от того и глуповат,
Бездельник.

Comment: Бездельник — имя собственное?